# google app engine persistence and intranet app

Tags: google-app-engine

Has anyone any tips with using gae on a project that could be easily switched from using the jpa persistence option (in the cloud) to running against a standard on-site sql server instance. I am starting a new project that will be hosted on gae or certain editions but there will be an enterprise version that will run on client sites.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A project which uses JPA or JDO may not work as it is on FAE because GAE does not support all the features. So you will have to consider the GAE limitations while implementing. I would recommend you go through the GAE documents and understand what are the limitations first so that you can identify compatibility issues and take necessary steps in that direction.